# How to add ChartJS code in Html2Pdf to view image

Tags: php, chart.js, html2pdf

I am using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/).

This is my php file and I have used javascript through which I am simply creating a chart and creating chart image after that.

```
<script>

            function done(){

                    var url=myLine.toBase64Image();
                    document.getElementById("url").src=url;
            }


        var MONTHS = [<?php echo '"' . implode('","', array_reverse($close_date_arr)) . '"' ?>];


        var config = {
          type: 'line',
          data: {

            labels: [<?php echo '"' . implode('","', array_reverse($close_date_arr)) . '"' ?>],

            datasets: [{
              label: "<?php echo $asx_code ?>",
              backgroundColor: '#ff6384', 
              borderColor:'#ff6384', 

              data: [<?php echo '"' . implode('","', array_reverse($close_price_arr)) . '"' ?>],
              fill: false,
            }]
          },
          options: {
               bezierCurve : false,
      animation: {
        onComplete: done
      },
            responsive: true,
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: ''
            },
            tooltips: {
              mode: 'index',
              intersect: false,
            },
            hover: {
              mode: 'nearest',
              intersect: true
            },
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                  display: true,
                  labelString: 'Month'
                }
              }],
              yAxes: [{
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                  display: true,
                  labelString: 'Value'
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        };


          var ctx = document.getElementById('canvascode').getContext('2d');
          window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);


        document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
          config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
            dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
              return randomScalingFactor();
            });

          });

          window.myLine.update();
        });

        var colorNames = Object.keys(window.chartColors);

      </script>
```

This is working absolutely fine but now I am stuck doing the same thing in [html2pdf](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf) . I want to include couple of `JS` files and generate my chart using `script` tag and then put image into my PDF file.

This is what I have done without any luck.

```
<?php 
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;


$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf();
$html2pdf->pdf->IncludeJS('Chart.bundle.js');
$html2pdf->pdf->IncludeJS('chart_utils.js');




$asx_code = 'CHK';

$url = 'https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/share/' . $asx_code . '/prices?interval=daily&count=365';
  //  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Execute
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

// Will dump a beauty json :3
$record_decode = json_decode($result);

$close_date_arr = array();
$close_price_arr = array();


    foreach ($record_decode->data as $current_data) {

        $close_price_arr[] = $current_data->close_price;

        $close_date_arr[] = date('F Y', strtotime($current_data->close_date));


    }

$str = '<canvas id="canvascode" style="display:none"></canvas>
<img id="url" style="width:400px; height:400px" />';

?>

<script>

        function done(){

                var url=myLine.toBase64Image();
                document.getElementById("url").src=url;
        }


    var MONTHS = [<?php echo '"' . implode('","', array_reverse($close_date_arr)) . '"' ?>];


    var config = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {

        labels: [<?php echo '"' . implode('","', array_reverse($close_date_arr)) . '"' ?>],

        datasets: [{
          label: "<?php echo $asx_code ?>",
          backgroundColor: '#ff6384', 
          borderColor:'#ff6384', 

          data: [<?php echo '"' . implode('","', array_reverse($close_price_arr)) . '"' ?>],
          fill: false,
        }]
      },
      options: {
           bezierCurve : false,
  animation: {
    onComplete: done
  },
        responsive: true,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: ''
        },
        tooltips: {
          mode: 'index',
          intersect: false,
        },
        hover: {
          mode: 'nearest',
          intersect: true
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Month'
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Value'
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    };


      var ctx = document.getElementById('canvascode').getContext('2d');
      window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);


    document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
      config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
        dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
          return randomScalingFactor();
        });

      });

      window.myLine.update();
    });

    var colorNames = Object.keys(window.chartColors);

  </script>

 <?php  
$html2pdf->writeHTML($str);
$html2pdf->output();

?>
```

When I try to generate PDF file, I am getting an error saying,

> Fatal error: Uncaught Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\HtmlParsingException: The html tag [canvas] is not known by Html2Pdf. You can create it and push it on the Html2Pdf GitHub project. in /var/www/html/htmlpdf/vendor/spipu/html2pdf/src/Html2Pdf.php:1435 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/htmlpdf/vendor/spipu/html2pdf/src/Html2Pdf.php(1043): Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf->_executeAction(Object(Spipu\Html2Pdf\Parsing\Node)) #1 /var/www/html/htmlpdf/vendor/spipu/html2pdf/src/Html2Pdf.php(749): Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf->_setNewPositionForNewLine(NULL) #2 /var/www/html/htmlpdf/vendor/spipu/html2pdf/src/Html2Pdf.php(1415): Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf->_setNewPage() #3 /var/www/html/htmlpdf/vendor/spipu/html2pdf/src/Html2Pdf.php(1401): Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf->_executeAction(Object(Spipu\Html2Pdf\Parsing\Node)) #4 /var/www/html/htmlpdf/vendor/spipu/html2pdf/src/Html2Pdf.php(595): Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf->_makeHTMLcode() #5 /var/www/html/htmlpdf/test.php(138): Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf->writeHTML('

Can someone guide me how can I generate my script here and put only my image into PDF.

Comment: This isn't going to work with any javascript charting library as HTML2PDF won't execute the script to generate the chart. The simplest approach is to generate your chart with a PHP charting library. Otherwise you might use node.js to run your javascript server-side.

Answer (score 2):

as the error message hints for: you'd have go to [Html2Pdf](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/issues) on Github and create a new issue there; in order to have tag `canvas` added into the next one release of the library - or try to use something else than a `canvas` to render the chart; other charting-libraries would also work with tag `div` or `svg`.

well, see [issue 372](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/issues/372) ...the author does not intent to add tag `canvas`.

therefore, you could only work around, eg. with `phantomJS`, to create a screenshot of the canvas and then use that as static image resource, in order to render it to PDF.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. At the moment, I cant change the library because I have made lot of things within this library so it would be ideal if I can get something to workaround using this lib itself.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave unless it's author would add tag `canvas`, in case this even is technically possible, there might be no way to add `canvas` into the generated PDF. this repository of mine would wrap `phantomJS` (it's a headless WebKit browser, install takes about 2GB): https://github.com/syslogic/php-phantomjs - this would be the only way I could imaging to get an image of the chart - in order to supply `html2pdf` with the content it expects as the input. basically, this is a web-service, which can be used to create screenshots. use `GD` to crop it to fit.

Comment: I just wonder, Cant we use SVG tag in my current lib HTML2PDF ? I mean there must be some sort of way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not with HTML2PDF but the error is with the events sequence to create the HTML2PDF. What I understand doing events as:

```
1.  Loading PHP Code
2.  Loading according to PHP and creating Charts/Canvas through JS
3.  Pringing HTML2PDF Output through PHP Code
```

The real problem is that Step No.3 is not waiting for completion of Step No.2. Thus, you have to create a trigger/event to start step No.3 on completion of Step No.2. Generally the HTML2PDF are created through JS as under:

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I agree with your above points and suggestions. But I have tried various things to achieve this (calling cURL etc) but I am still not able to solve this out. Can you please help me to achieve this if possible.

Comment: Curl will not be helpful to you as curl is server side code running thus you have to fire the event as in client side thus use JavaScript code to fire event after chart is loaded. Search Google with chart and html2pdf you will find many examples but have to implement according to your needs